# How to avoid MobileDatePicker fire onAccept when users click outside the calendar?

Tags: input, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I have a MobileDatePicker. After open the calendar I want this only updates the date when the user clicks over the "OK" button. But this is updating the date after clicking outside the calendar too because the onAccept is fired when users click outside the calendar.